# Formatting currency with commas in Javascript for Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

When adding Javascript to a PDF, is it possible for me to print a float so that it looks like this: $50,0000?

I don't care about internationalization.

I can use util.printf, but it won't put the commas in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to do it by javascript. Does this help you.

```
formatNumber
function formatNumber( num ) {
    var decimalPart = '';
    num = num.toString();
    if ( num.indexOf( '.' ) != -1 ) {
        decimalPart = '.'+ num.split( '.' )[1];
        num = parseInt(num.split( '.' )[0]);
    }
    var array = num.toString().split( '' );
    var index = -3;
    while ( array.length + index > 0 ) {
        array.splice( index, 0, ',' );
        index -= 4;
    }
    return array.join( '' ) + decimalPart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple add commas function is:

```
function addCommas(num) {
  var num = String(num);
  var bits, num0, s, f, len, sign = '', result = [];

  if (/^[+-]/.test(num)) {
    sign = num.substring(0,1);
    num = num.substring(1);
  }

  bits = String(num).split('.');
  num0 = bits[0];
  s = 0, f = num0.length % 3 ;
  len = num0.length;

  if (num0.length > 3) {

    while (f <= len) {
      f && result.push(num0.substring(s, f));
      s = f;
      f += 3;
    }
    result = result.join(',') + (bits[1]? '.' + bits[1] : '');
  }
  return sign + (s? result : num);
}
```

There are probably a million similar functions, try Google.

#### Edit

Fixed issue where length > 6 and num % 3 == 0
Added support for -ve numbers

Answer (score 1):

A little late but...

printf *will* add commas.

```
util.printf("%,0.0f", numberValue);
```

[See JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference for more...](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.1246.html)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will also work for negative numbers as well.

```
function addCommas( num ) {
    var parts = num.toString(10).split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].reverse().replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1,").reverse();
    return parts.join(".");
}   

String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQZfa/2/)